# Dynamic Linq Group By

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, group-by, dynamic-linq

I am currently building reports and have a need to Group columns dynamically, depending on user's choice. Now, assuming that the situation is fixed on all columns, the query would be as follows:

```
var groupedInvoiceItems = invoiceItems.GroupBy(x => new { x.SalesInvoice.name, x.SalesInvoice.currencyISO, x.CatalogProduct });
```

Doing so would return results as desired, IGrouping. I would then run a loop to process the necessary data as below:

```
foreach (var groupedInvoiceItem in groupedInvoiceItems)
{
    // Perform work here
}
```

Now, the headache comes in when I try to make the Grouping dynamic by using Dynamic Linq. The query is as follows:

```
var groupedInvoiceItems = invoiceItems.GroupBy("new (SalesInvoice.name, SalesInvoice.currencyISO, CatalogProduct)", "it");
```

The problem with this is that it does not return IGrouping anymore. Hence, my foreach loop no longer works. Is there any solution to the matter? I tried casting IGrouping to the Dynamic query but to no avail. Help is needed urgently.

Comment: How come your code is compiling? GroupBy expects a Func and you are passing two strings!

Comment: @RahulSingh this is dynamic linq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the `GroupBy` is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<DynamicClass,InvoiceItem>>`, so you can proceed by something like:

```
foreach (IGrouping<DynamicClass,InvoiceItem> invoiceItemGroup in groupedInvoiceItems)
{

}
```

Comment: Nice. This works indeed. I was going round and round trying to get IGrouping<InvoiceItem, anonymous>. Didn't know Dynamic changes things. Marked as answer, cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You should do the grouping then select the specified attributes to iterate throw them in the foreach loop. Try this out:

```
var groupedInvoiceItems = invoiceItems.GroupBy("SalesInvoice.name","it").GroupBy("SalesInvoice.currencyISO","it").GroupBy("CatalogProduct","it").Select("new (it.SalesInvoice.name,it.SalesInvoice.currencyISO,it.CatalogProduct)");
```

Hope this works.

Comment: If Linq functions as it is, you're not required to Select. Also, it's rather unnecessary to do GroupBy and then further GroupBy. You're just causing some performance issues by nesting them.